# what's the difference between global average and local average in zero centering processing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, normalization

It's necessary to do zero-centering during the image preprocessing phase.

But I don't know why some papers substract the global average (the average among the whole training set), while others just substract the local average (the average among each of the mini-batches). Could you please give an explanation clarifying the idea?

**PS**: In zero-centering, do we substract the average for each channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero-centering as a preprocessing step has various advantages, but to clear things up here, it only makes sense to apply this preprocessing if you have a reason to believe that different **input features have different scales** (or units), but they should be of approximately equal importance to the learning algorithm. In case of images, the relative scales of pixels are already approximately equal (and in range from 0 to 255), so it is not strictly necessary to perform this additional preprocessing step. [Find more Information here](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/)

The normalization within a minibatch is usually called "Batch Normalization" and follows along the idea to address the vanishing / exploding Gradient Problem and the Problem that **the Distribution of each layer's Inputs changes during Training as the Parameters of the previous layers Change. By zero-centering and normalizing before each layer the Network learns to cope with this** "Internal Covariate Shift". [Find more Information here](https://books.google.de/books?id=khpYDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA284&lpg=PA284&dq=minibatch%20zero%20centering&source=bl&ots=kLBAKNBkiZ&sig=NbGA4HN7wA7R9AEpUJl-pb8Uea4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOo-bGhcHbAhXqCcAKHXbWCf8Q6AEIRzAD#v=onepage&q=minibatch%20zero%20centering&f=false)

**PS:** Zero-centering as a preprocessing step is either done by dividing by the Standard Deviation or scaling according to the min / max values of your Distribution (**this is usually done over all channels** / Features, depending on your data and whether you want them to have the same influence on the Training, exceptions are possible though).